# Load content into specific div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this element:

```
<div data-load-module="list-users"></div>
```

And this JS to load the specific module:

```
if($('[data-load-module]').length) {
    var datas = $('[data-load-module]').attr('data-load-module');

    var url = 'assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php';

    $(this).load(url, function() {
        ...
    });
}
```

The line `$(this).load()` do not load my module.

I do not want to add an `id` or another `class`.

How can I specify that I want the content loads into the `this` div ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think to the `div` I mentioned ?

Comment: `$(this)` does not refer to the div, it is the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `this` does not refer to the div element commonly it may refer to `window` object.

---

If you would like to load content into the same div then cache the selector in a variable and use it.

```
var $div = $('[data-load-module]');
if($div.length) {
    var datas = $div.attr('data-load-module');    
    var url = 'assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php';    
    $div.load(url);
}
```

---

In case there are multiple divs then use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over them and inside the callback use `this` to refer the element.

```
$('[data-load-module]').each(function(){
    var datas = $(this).attr('data-load-module');    
    var url = 'assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php';    
    $(this).load(url);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.data-load-module').each(function(i) {
    $(this).load(...)
});
```

Providing `.data-load-module` is your class then you can reference the divs from this class this way. Otherwise `this` doesn't refer to anything in your code.